# React Firebase app auth service does not work in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, webpack, google-cloud-firestore

I have set up a React authorization through the Google account on my web app, that does not really work in production, however, works on the localhost. Here is the message from the dev mode (that perhaps may impact): The issue is that the google sign-in modal instantly disappears from the screen!

```
It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
the individual SDK components you intend to use.

import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/<PACKAGE>';
```

What may be an error and the solution here? I use the real-time database to modify values (that actually properly work) and auth service for google accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you are getting is telling you how to fix the issue. The problem is the way you are importing the Firebase SDK. If you have something different as the below, I would recommend you to change it:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/storage';//if using Firebase storage, if not, set the right component.
```

Comment: is this okay, that firebase takes ages to start the authorization window?

Comment: and it crashes in the end

Answer (score 1):

You just need go to your Firebase console and under 'Sign-in method', scroll down to the 'Authorized domains' tab, and add your Production app domain.